# golang msgpck custom marchalling

Tags: go, msgpack

I'm working on a golang project which is using msgpack.  In the code the following comment exists

```
// We use a fast path for hot structs.
```

Under this there are certain structs which implements its own marshall method and has code something similar to the following

```
func (z *struct) MarshalMsg(b []byte) (o []byte, err error) {
    o = msgp.Require(b, z.Msgsize())

    // string "Field1"
    o = append(o, 0x88, 0xa6, 0x54, 0x65, 0x61, 0x6d, 0x49, 0x64)

    o = msgp.AppendString(o, z.Field1)

    // string "Field2"
    o = append(o, 0xa6, 0x55, 0x73, 0x65, 0x72, 0x49, 0x64)
    o = msgp.AppendString(o, z.Field2)

    // string "Field3"
    o = append(o, 0xa5, 0x52, 0x6f, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x73)
    o = msgp.AppendString(o, z.Field3)
    return
}
```

I am not sure what this code does exactly, + what do you mean by `hot structs` I assume its custom marshalling ? Also what does the line  `append(o, 0xa5, 0x52, 0x6f, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x73)` do ?

Answer (score 0):

## code specific answer

First of all your code is automatically generated by the MessagePack and should not be edited.

All the `apend(o, ...)` functions add hexadecimal encoded bytes to the byte array. Each append is for one field within the struct with the given tags in the form of

```golang
type test struct {
    Bar string `msg:"bar"`
}
```

For example the "field3" append function. If you would print it as a string the result is as follows: `�Roles`

Here my code:

```golang
var b = []byte{}
b = append(b, 0xa5, 0x52, 0x6f, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x73)
fmt.Println(string(b))
```

For the second field: `�UserId`

And for the first field: `��TeamId`

The first function `msgp.Require` that the capacity of the byte array - the length of the array is bigger or equal to some message size field defined within the struct.
See the documentation https://godoc.org/github.com/tinylib/msgp/msgp#Require.

#msgp package
The package is a simple code generator which generates serializing methods for the MessagePack. (https://github.com/tinylib/msgp/wiki/Using-the-Code-Generator)

I highly recommend to read the wiki and the getting started section. (https://github.com/tinylib/msgp/wiki/Getting-Started)